# I press the home button of emulator or phone then reopen the app it is starting video from pause state in android studio exoplayer

Tags: java, android

when I press the home button or close app and open the emulator or phone then reopen the app it is starting video from pause state to continue in android studio exoplayer

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Kindly edit your question and the code you have already written and you are struggling with (as a minimal example please). Second: what is your problem with the actual behavior?

Comment: show the code ,edit your question with the code

Comment: Can you share me the code for how to pause and play activity code using exoplayer

Comment: i don't know to how to solve this activity

Comment: protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        pausePlayer();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startPlayer();
    }

Comment: Example:Udemy Application

Comment: i'm created application for online study.i have an error in video resume pause activity.when i close the video and again open the video will be start with 0(initial)

Comment: so i need to change the pause resume.when i logout the video will be pause state.again open the app the video will start resume position not initial position.so pls give me some ides for exoplayer androd java.

Comment: Forr Ur refernce


https://github.com/suvethasubramaniyan/KTU-Online-Study/blob/KTU-FIRST-UPDATE/src/main/java/com/nxtlogic/ktuonlinestudy/VideoViewActivity.java